# Installing Bundle for Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, bundle

I am trying to install bundle and I keep on getting errors about specific gems not being installed. For example, my byebug debugger was not installed I had to install that, and my eventmachine was not installed, and now my json is not installed I install json and when I run

```
#bundle install
```

I still get the:

```
An error occurred while installing json (1..7.7), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that 'gem install json -v '1.7.7' succeeds before bundling
```

How can I successfully install bundle?

edit: `gem install json -v '1.7.7'` I get the following error:
[new error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vQ2AQ.png)

Comment: what OS are you running ?

Comment: I am running Ubtunu 14.0X

Comment: run `gem install json -v '1.7.7'` separately.  If it installs successfully run bundle install, otherwise you'll get a more in depth error on what happened.

Comment: I get an new error message. make failed in this instance. Please see edits in the question

Comment: Please post text, not links to images.

Comment: I can't unfortunately post images just yet until I reach 10 points. So stackoverflow automatically converts them into links.